# Can you use drush to update to a different module version?

Tags: 7, drush

I know you can download a specific version.

Example: `drush dl webform-7.x-3.24`

According to "drush up" the webform module is up to date. Thats fine but now I want to update the webform module to use version 4.

Is there such a thing as `drush up webform-7.x-4.12`, or is it still a manual process?

EDIT:

Doing `drush dl webform-7.x-4.12` returns 
"Install location /var/www/_public/xxxxxx/sites/all/modules/webform already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n):"

Comment: `drush dl webform --select` ?

Comment: (facepalm) "drush dl" asks if you want to do an override. Thanks @Clive.